# How to bring all indexed array object into one associative array object

Tags: php

I have a php array object `$images` if I print this array by `print_r($images)`, I gets following structure.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [image_name] => 1.jpg
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [image_name] => 2.jpg
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [image_name] => 3.jpg
        )
)
```

and I want to convert its structure as;

```
Array
(
    [image_name] => stdClass Object
        (
            [0] => 1.jpg
            [1] => 2.jpg
            [2] => 3.jpg
        )
)
```

Some one please suggest me a function to do that in php.

Comment: Is it always going to have the same format?

Comment: yes, I will get only the specified format.

Comment: Why should it output an array with an object inside? Are you sure it should not just be an array?

Comment: I used `print_r()` to output it.

Comment: I think @SverriM.Olsen asked you you want output as `stdClass Object` normally array is used, just to clarify if it was a mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a simple loop.

```
$imagesArray = ['image_name' => new \stdClass()];
$counter = 0;
foreach ($images as $image) {
    $imagesArray['image_name']->$counter = $image->image_name;
    $counter++;
}
```

**Explanation**

I've first created an array `$imagesArray` with one element of stdClass, then I put the `image_name` as key. Then by using foreach loop of array of images `$images`, every `$image` is stdClass object, you just get the `image_name` property and assign it to the `image_name` object as `$counter`, which is just an integer.

Comment: `$imagesArray` will be an array not object

Comment: @VasilShaddix Yeah, its working. What you did? I mean Can you explain it. Thanx.

Comment: perfect! one trick: `$imagesArray['image_name']->{$counter++} = $image->image_name;` instead of 2 lines :)

Comment: @VasilShaddix, Now it is a good answer, some comment/explanation will make it great.

Comment: You create an array with one element of stdClass, i put the 'image_name' as key. Then you use foreach to loop through your array of images. Every $image is stdClass object, you just get the image_name property and assign it to the image_name object as $counter, which is just an integer.I wouldn't use such structure as @bansi suggested. Hope you could understand it.

Comment: Okay, I'll edit this your answer. Thanx for your responsiveness.